# How to import popper.js?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, popper.js

It seems to be a lame question, but I cannot figure it out. How to import popper.js which comes together with Bootstrap 4 beta?

I use Bower, and I've installed Bootstrap 4 beta. Now in the `bower_components` folder, there is the `popper.js` directory, which contains a few sub-folders. The problem is there is no `dist` folder and the `popper.min.js` file.

Bootstrap 4 guide links to CDN: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js`.

How to import `popper.js` without CDN? Where to find the `popper.min.js` file?

EDIT: Even if I download a `zip` file from the popper.js website, it contains the same files as I've downloaded from `Bower`.

Comment: Download it (from the CDN) to your server directory, and refer from there?!

Comment: The file you have linked to creates a `Popper` variable, so downloading that file and importing it via `<script>` should work.

Comment: I would like to user `bower` to be able to easily update scripts in future.

Comment: Bower is deprecated, use npm

Answer (score 42):

I ran into the same problem.

I downloaded the 'popper.min.js' file from the CDN on the bootstrap website.

See here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.4.4/cjs/popper.min.js

Easier than compiling the project.

**Important:** You must include popper after jquery but BEFORE bootstrap.

Comment: Dude you're my hero. Learning web dev in my free time, everyones talking about Bower and Yarn etc. Then you're like, just include this.

Comment: The cool part about this approach and that you are already behind the latest version of my library and you are missing some important fixes. That's why dependency managers exist.

Comment: @FezVrasta What do you mean?

Comment: If you copy-paste code without use a dependency manager you will miss important updates.

Comment: @FezVrasta Makes sense. But I'm sure the people who used it are aware because it is a local file?

Comment: Most of people don't realize how much important is to keep the dependencies up to date

Comment: @FezVrasta True

Comment: Yeah, also important crashes. and dependecy hell.

Comment: Why is this file all commented out?

Comment: I don't understand this officious tone either. On the official Bootstrap intro page it tells you to include this: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-..."</script>. That's a specific version. You might as well download it, especially if you want potentially to use offline/dodgy Net connection, and be sure you've got it in a location chosen by you. PS yes, I use an HTML server locally on my own machine and network...

Answer (score 17):

The official way to install Popper.js is trough npm, Yarn or NuGet.

Use either one of the following commands :

```
npm i popper.js
yarn add popper.js
PM> Install-Package popper.js
```

Everything is described in the library readme.

Regarding the "downloads the zip", the zip clearly states that it contains the *source code* of the library.

**Edit**:

Starting from version `1.12.0`, Popper.js is available as Bower dependency.

This installation method is going to be supported only for the `1.x` version of Popper.js and will be removed in `2.x`.

You should migrate your dependencies management to a modern system like npm or Yarn, as Bower suggests as well.

Comment: It's not easy way. When installing Bootstrap 4 via Bower it's downloading non-compiled popper.js, but downloaded jQuery is "ready to go".

Comment: Bower is deprecated, you should use npm

Comment: npm doesn't seem to install the actual popper.js file. Is there another step after that?

Comment: You find the files in the dist folder. Make sure to install popper.js, not "popper"

Comment: Fez Vrasta, you just saved me hours. npm install *popper.js* --save

Answer (score 8):

#### Ways to get popper.js: Package, CDN, and Local file

The best way depends on whether you have a project with a package manager like npm.

**Package manager**
If you're using a package manager, use it to get popper.js like this:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

**CDN**
For a prototype or playground environment (like http://codepen.io) or may just want a url to a CDN file:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.min.js

*note: Bootstrap 4 requires the versions under the **umd** path [(more info on popper/bs4)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45966415/700206).*

**Local file**

Just save one of the CDN files to use locally. For example, paste one of these URLs in a browser, then Save As... to get a local copy.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.min.js

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Tried different approches, but this one worked for me.
Read the instruction from http://getbootstrap.com/.

**Copy the CDN paths of Javascripts (Popper, jQuery and Bootstrap) in same manner (it is important) as given.**

[image]

```html
<head>
//Path to jQuery
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

////Path to Popper - it is for dropsdowns etc in bootstrap
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

//Path to bootsrap
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

I really don't understand why Javascript world trying to do thing more complicated. Why not just download and include in html? Trying to have something like Maven in Java? But we have to manually include it in html anyway? So, what is the point? Maybe someday I will understand but not now.

This is how I can get it

- download & install NodeJs
- run "npm install popper.js --save"
- then I get this message

  popper.js@1.12.7
  added 1 package in 1.215s
- then where is "add package" ? very informative , right? I found it in my C:\Users\surasin\node_modules\popper.js\dist

Hope this help

Comment: Too much opinion based answer w/o/ good amount of technical resources.

Comment: I also don`t understand why bootstrap 4 includes external popper.js, It means bootstrap makes more complicated instead of easy when upgrading to the latest versions.

Answer (score 3):

add popper**.js** as dependency instead of popper (only): see the difference in bold.

> yarn add popper.js , instead of
>   yarn add popper

it makes the difference.

and include the script according your needs:

as html or
the library access as a dependency in SPA applications like react or angular

Answer (score 3):

IN bootstrap 4 you need to add popper js for tooltip, I also don`t understand why bootstrap 4 includes external popper.js, It means bootstrap makes more complicated instead of easy when upgrading to the latest versions.

You can import popper js before bootstrap on angular or a simple html, Angular import would be like this

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

then go to 
    .angular-cli.json and change the order like below.

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js", 
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",              
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
```

you can also use CDN direct call popper js into your any project.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.min.js

Answer (score 1):

I deleted any existing popper directories, then ran

```
npm install --save popper.js angular-popper
```

Answer (score 1):

first install propperJs from by yarn

```
yarn add popper.js
```

then you can import it like this

```
import Popper from "popper.js";
```

Comment: The import statement should be `import Popper from "@popperjs/core";`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Popper.js [doesn't provide compiled files](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/issues/274) on its GitHub repository. Therefore, one has to compile the project on his/her own or download compiled files from CDNs. It cannot be automatically imported.

Comment: The suggested way is to use npm actually

Answer (score 0):

You can download and import all of Bootstrap, and Popper, with a single command using [Fetch Injection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-inject):

```
fetchInject([
  'https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/popper.js/1.0.0-beta.3/popper.min.js'
], fetchInject([
  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.slim.min.js',
  'https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js'
]));
```

Add CSS files if you need those too. Adjust versions and external sources to meet your needs and consider using sub-resource integrity checking if you're not hosting the files on your own domain or don't trust the source.

Answer (score 0):

Install `popper.js` with spesific version number like this:

```
bower install popper.js@^1.16.0
```

Now u can find `dist` folder and `popper.min.js` file.