# How to import popper.js? (not with a CDN, installed with NPM)

Tags: javascript, npm, import

I am aware there is other similar questions such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650583/how-to-import-popper-js). However mine is quite different.

I would like to know how to import Popper.js using the `import` directive. So far I have this on my `app.js` (but it does not work yet)

```
import * as popper from 'popper.js'
window.popper = popper
```

But I have to mangle every example I find on the Internet with `popper.`. Moreover this include takes two lines while the traditional writing `window.popper = require('popper.js')` takes only one line.

What is the correct way to import Popper.js and other similar JS libraries?

Comment: `import Popper from 'popper.js';` is enough to use it. The window assignment is needed only by Bootstrap

Comment: No it is not, because `Popper` is therefore not globally accessible. I have to put it into `document.Popper`. So it requires an additional line.

Comment: If you are using ES modules you shouldn't rely on globally accessible modules

Comment: Unfortunately I need this :(

Comment: Then just assign it to window after you import it as I described above

Comment: @FezVrasta Is this the same import for Tooltip.js ?