# Bootstrap 4 popper is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm trying to get a dropdown going and whenever I click on the button I get `TypeError: popper is undefined`.

I tried importing the bundle instead of `bootstrap`

```
// import "bootstrap";
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js';
```

I tried importing `jquery` first

```
import "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
```

I tried importing popper as well

```
import "popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js";
import "jquery";
import "bootstrap";
```

I also tried including popper from a CDN before any other scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

And I tried just about any combination of imports mentioned above, still getting this error, even when I can access `Popper` in the console.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between dropdown luri-eayq">
   <a href="/messages" class="btn btn-light flex-1 py-3 rounded-0">
      Messages
   </a>
   <a href="/phonebook" class="btn btn-light flex-1 py-3 rounded-0">
      Phonebook
   </a>
   <button id="dd" class="btn btn-light flex-1 py-3 rounded-0 mt-0" data-toggle="dropwdown">
      More
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="/problems">Problems</a></div>
</div>
```

I then call the following, since it's a dynamically generated element

```
$("#dd").dropdown();
```

My question is different than the suggested, because I explain that I already tried all of the suggested solutions and none worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import popper.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650583/how-to-import-popper-js)

Comment: popper must be before bootstrap.. since bootstrap depends on popper and its not loaded yet. popper depends on jquery so should be like the suggested answer.

Comment: You have a typo in `data-toggle="dropwdown"` - should be `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Comment: @Cocowalla valid, but do you suppose that's related to the error?

Comment: Try it and see :)  I've seen the same error when specifying an incorrect `data-target`, so I thought it worth mentioning

Comment: @Cocowalla unfortunately, in today's world, things are moving so fast I don't even remember from which project that was a part of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use the bundled bootstrap popper by importing

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

See the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/dropdowns/).

Or use the **UDM** Version of popper, see details below.

**Steps to use popper**

I like package managers. So here goes:

```
npm init
```

Just say yes to everything..

```
npm install bootstrap --save
npm install jquery --save
npm install popper.js --save
```

I created two folders js and css with an index.html file as follows:

```
 index.html
 package.json
 package-lock.json
 |_ js
 |_ css
 |_ node_modules
     |_ bootstrap
       |_ dist
     |_ jquery
       |_ dist
     |_ popper.js
       |_ dist
          |_udm
          |_esm
```

I then copied the files from the dist folder in various libraries located in node_modules to the css and js folders. With the exception of popper, **use the popper.js file or popper.min.js file located in the dist/udm folder**

The contents of the index.html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Popper Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown button
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/popper.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

To run the example I used:
http-server found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)
By running

```
npm install http-server -g
http-server
```

**If you have not used the UDM version then**
Opening chrome and going to http://127.0.0.1:8080. Brings up my page, hitting F12 and then trying to press the dropdown fails with the error message:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's dropdowns require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org/)
    at c.t.toggle (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.c._jQueryInterface [as dropdown] (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Either use the **UDM** version described above or the bundled bootstrap version by switching from:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> -->
```

to :

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/js/popper.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Works.

Versions implemented were:

- **bootstrap**: 4.2.1
- **jquery**: 3.3.1
- **popper.js**: 1.14.6

Answer (score 2):

try to import this order:

1. jquery
2. popper
3. bootstrap

for example:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome John. Good answer, I tried it too thinking that's correct, but it's not working.

Comment: you should refresh your page by pressing ctrl+F5. (refresh by clearing cache)

Comment: The reason the version of popper.js does not work is because it is the wrong distribution it should be the udm version of popper, located in the dist/udm folder.